# Redistributing LGPL source code or GPL packages on a BSD Licensed package

Tags: gpl, lgpl, bsd, redistribution

I have a python project licensed under BSD-License.
On its bottom I use a **source code** written in C++ which is licensed as `LGPL` and I have an *optional* dependency on a **python package** licensed under `GPL`.

I've been told that I should  add licensing information of both of these packages in my original license file (which contains only the BSD-3-Clause License) but I cannot figure out (from searching the internet) what and how I should add it (in order to be formal).

Comment: Are you distributing only your own Python project (which you said is BSD licensed), or are you also distributing the (L)GPL code? Having a dependency does not generally mean you distribute anything. My code has a dependency on and 'uses' Microsoft Windows, but I don't need Microsoft's permission to distribute my code.

Comment: Inside my project I have the code of another project. This is LGPL. I also have an optional dependency on another package that is GPL. I've been pointed out that I should add it inside my license. That is what brought me here in the first place. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/ysig/GraKeL/tree/0.1a6#license) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't matter what "dependencies" you have. It matters what code you are distributing. If you distribute GPL code, you must abide by its terms. You can't just say "well, it's an *optional* dependency" and pretend it doesn't apply to you. If you distribute it, then you must abide by the GPL, which of course means you must include the license text. If you don't distribute it, then you don't need to abide by it.

Comment: So the only **code** I am *redistributing* "as is" inside my package is the LGPL. Also it came out as a variant of pybliss (see Code and Documentation [here](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/)), which didn't contain a license, and uses the C++ version 0.5 of bliss (that is not licensed either). On the other hand the latest version of bliss 0.73 contains a license that is LGPL (which is not the version I use).

Comment: So if my project should include this license (which I have not understood) what should I add to [my license file](https://github.com/ysig/GraKeL/blob/0.1a6/LICENSE) (because [the LGPL license file is huge](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html))? Concerning the other package (the GPL) the user should install as `pip install ..` to uncover a functionality of my package (where I import it as `from library import tools`). Should I include that also? And if yes how? Tons of thanks btw :)

Comment: If the version of the library you use does not give you a license, then that means you may not copy and redistribute it to others. You should switch to a version which states the license such as LGPL. Just because the current version of the library uses the LGPL, does not mean the older version that you are using does.

Comment: Asking a user to run 'pip install foo' is not redistributing foo. It is basically just telling the user "in order to use my program you'll have to install 'foo', and here's the command to do that." It would be a similar situation if you wrote a program that required Microsoft Word to be installed. Clearly, the user will have to install that program of her own accord and accept whatever license Microsoft offers for that program, but you don't need a license from Microsoft in order to write and distribute a program that interoperates with Microsoft Word.

Comment: So in the first case, what should I add to my license file?

Comment: A grey area is that if you create a program that depends on details of a GPL program (even if optionally) it could be deemed a derivative, and thus only distributable under GPL. Sure, details of the dependency are crucial.